Migration pattern for logic too complex to cover it with SQL
When you create migration in EF Core you can spice it up with arbitrary SQL query. Yet there is a limit to it -- maybe the migration is too complex in technical sense (i.e the SQL cannot handle it) or in readability sense (expressing the logic in SQL is too muddy). In short when migration logic can be only expressed in regular EF Core C# code with queries, filters, loops, ifs, etc.
Which leads to the question what are the patterns/solutions to handle/organize it?
So far I came up with idea of "freezing" type definitons (by copying them) of context, table models, and call of them let's say "FrozenVersion". Then on migration check if upcoming migration contains the "hot" step -- if yes, migrate it up to this step using FrozenVersion, execute special logic using this version, then disconnect from DB, switch to regular/current version of DB context, and models, connect back to DB, and migrate the rest using this version.
Clarification: this is general question about pattern which starts with "assume SQL is not enough for migration..." in the same sense as patterns for specific algorithms start "assume you have more data than RAM...".

I have yet too see an overly complex SQL query which cannot split up into smaller queries or implemented by a stored procedure in a sufficiently clean way.

@DocBrown you are thinking purely in technical terms. Are you aware of recommendation that you should not write code that is at your peak of abilities? This translate to avoiding me writing SQL patched all over internet, half-understanding it, and year later crying because I completely don't understand what I wrote previously. Not to mention that DB of my choice does not support SP :-).

@greenoldman No guideline is going to protect you from not leveraging the tools you're working with. The approach you are suggesting (and the limitations you bring up in the comment) are not the idiomatic intended use case for EF. If you struggle leveraging the tool, it would be better to upskill rather than try and come up with a different approach based on not feeling confident enough to write something readable.

@Flater you are not reading what I am saying. Ok, let's say I will get PhD even for this very reason, and once I write migration solely in SQL what next? In time my SQL skills will diminish because I don't use it daily, because I don't need to. And then when when I get back to my old code, I will need again to upskill? What gain is there (apart from looking cool from time to time)? It is true for every skill or tool, if you don't use axe every day better do not be a hero and don't "upskill" just on a Christmas day. This is even apart from consideration if a tool is a fit for a job.

@greenoldman: my personal experience with this community is that responses are much better received here when the overall tone stays polite and constructive. Personal accusations are not welcome here.

@greenoldman, you seem to be touching on very deep issues like skills reproduction, and the costs/benefits of forgetting across time. The standard solution to nasty transitional logic, is to eventually forget and abandon old versions, and either run with just the latest version which implicitly incorporates past learning, or start again entirely from a clean slate. There's no magic wand where a person can remain abreast of every iteration of a varying design - it becomes more and more complicated to do so with each step.

@Steve I am simply evaluating my options here, and I would like to make honest evaluation, not just blindly jump on recommendation/guideline X. After all it is me who will pay the cost of the maintenance. So sure, I am including such factors as forgetting not-used knowledge too. And while I asked this question while I currently have a problem, the question is in general sense, so starting from clean start has limited use (you cannot go from user to user and fix data manually in general).

@greenoldman, options for what? The way you deal with users is to order them all to upgrade to a currently maintained version, or you cut them loose if they will not, or you charge them enough to keep enough staff on hand who remember or document every detail of every version in use. And if you can't do any of these things then you're the one that folds, and your customers are cut loose anyway because their software supplier is now a wound-up bankrupt. That's the hard reality of how retailed software has actually been working for decades now.

@greenoldman: I am reading what you're saying, I'm just trying to take you out of the complicated scenario you're in to get you to look at this big picture and come up with a strategy to help deal with this. You're stuck to the path you've set yourself on and aren't really evaluating if there are better paths ahead. If you remain apprehensive of learning to better leverage the tools that you're working with; then you will keep struggling over and over again, even if you manage to sidestep one of these obstacles.

@greenoldman: The secondary issues you bring up (not being able to write readable code, half-understanding your work, completely not understanding your work over time, not wanting to learn a skill on the possibility that you might not need it permanently, ...) are all indicators that you have an ongoing struggle with the skillset for your role. That's not meant to be mean, it's meant to indicate to you that things get way easier when you upskill. A dev who is afraid of the code they write because they fear not understanding it, is holding themselves back and not delivering what they could.

Also, and again not meant to be mean but informative; your apprehension on the topics I just listed also makes me wonder if your claim that the migration is impossibly complex is more so an indicator of you not having the full knowledge to come up with the appropriate solution; rather than it being universally impossible to do so in the first place. You provide no contextual details so I can't confirm this suspicion, but based on all the apprehension and doubt you bring to the table, it does raise a valid question whether your take on the technical implementation is possibly incomplete.

I guess what you really want to know is, is there an approach to avoid the usage of "MigrationBuilder.Sql" by including LINQ queries into a migration. Is that your question?

@Flater I am not native English speaker so I am unable to further explain this is general question about pattern. If it helps "let's assume is it too complex". I am evaluating SQL somewhere else (so there I cover the path "SQL is enough") and here I would like to evaluate the other alternative -- "SQL is not enough". If it helps consider question "sorting algorithm with data size bigger than RAM" and then counter comments "do you really have more data than RAM, maybe you didn't count it correctly; RAM is cheap you should buy more".

@DocBrown yes, yes, and once again yes :-). I want to know more. And while evaluating such path (not using SQL) how to tackle it in most efficient way (in sense of code size, readability, maintenance, etc.),

@greenoldman: well, SQL is probably the most compact solution for most of these problems, and in my eyes often the most readable and maintainable approach, so this is very opinionated and not objectively answerable. But if you stick to the technical question - including LINQ queries instead of SQL in a migration - that would be a good question for Stackoverflow, since it is a coding question about entity framework.

... maybe this Stackoverflow question EF Core: Add custom LINQ in Up method of Migration class contains what you are looking for

The idea behind the MigrationBuilder  class is IMHO the other way round:

It contains C# methods for the most common Schema changes as well as the most common data migrations,

and in case the standard methods of a MigrationBuilder cannot handle a migration, there is MigrationBuilder.Sql as the tool for handling any kind of complex migration.


In my experience, the number of cases which cannot be handled by these tools is quite rare. The SQL dialect of any DBMS I know allows to manipulate any kind of internal structure, all kind of things the standard MigrationBuilder methods don't provide.
Now you raised the question what to do when both of the former methods don't seem to be sufficient, and if it is possible to implement, for example, a complex data migration, without SQL, fully in C#, making use of tools like LINQ. Some reasons to justify this step are quite debatable, especially when it comes to "half-knowledge of SQL", because

a certain knowledge of SQL is IMHO mandatory for anyone who calls themselves a professsional database programmer

when the SQL gets "too muddy", I think chances are high it can be refactored into smaller, cleaner steps

when a programmer has trouble to implement a complex migration with SQL in a clean way, they can always ask at a site like Stackoverflow or Codereview.Stackexchange


Still I think your question is certainly justified since I can imagine a few cases where it is indeed easier to implement something in C# than in SQL.
Maybe one needs to include a special library to make some complex technical calculation during a migration, maybe one wants to make use of things provided by the .Net framework or other existing code. For such cases, this Stackoverflow Q&A demonstrates how to get direct access to the database context during a migration, which is all one needs to implement arbitrary C# code which runs as part of migration step.
My priorities for designing a migration would always be (1) MigrationBuilder's standard methods, (2) the Sql method, and (3) custom C#. At least I would not lightheartly choose (3) over (2) just because to avoid SQL programming.

Thank you, but please keep at heart your own recommendation. It is seriously annoying to be patronized again and again just because I asked shocking/unpopular question. Example -- where did I write "just to avoid writing SQL"? It is your assumption and is plain false. I appreciate your input and help but it would be better without such remarks, let's stick to technical aspects. Option (3) is something I work on to have it in my toolbox but "having" does not mean "using". Yet I want to have it well thought of, and well prepared. And with your help (link to SO) it takes better shapes it had -).

@greenoldman:  "where did I write "just to avoid writing SQL" - in your very first comments below your own question? At least that is how I understood them. And what makes you think your question is unpopular? It got two upvotes (one from me, btw.,), and only one downvote.

Oh, I see :-) Maybe I was not clear enough about it -- I am not for avoiding XYZ per se, but avoiding writing XYZ code at the limits of my knowledge using pieces grabbed all over internet (here XYZ=SQL). As for popularity -- I noticed how fast it got downvote and request for closing it :-).

@greenoldman: the downvotes and close votes are quite normal here, because there are some hardliners in the community which downvote and close vote everything which contains just a minor sign of being too broad. The wording "what are the patterns/solutions" is often a red flag for them (and others), since it is literally a list of things question, and also a "shopping for patterns" question. ...

... you will get better reactions when you ask for "an approach (for this specific problem)" instead of "a list of patterns".

I think here you have to go back to the general practice of:

Testing your upgrades/migrations. ie, can v1 migrate to v2,v3,v4 without data loss
Checking the version you are upgrading is on that tested list before upgrading.

If you can't make the jump from v1 to v9, then error out and tell the user to go through whatever intermediate steps are required.
To clarify, if there is some DB transformation that's impossible to do with EF migrations. Don't try and force it into EF migrations with duplicate models and such.
Just do it with sql scripts as a special upgrade, and don't allow migrations that span the problem version (or any other untested upgrade) to run at all.
Second clarification from conversation in comments:
The question asker does not have a deployment or upgrade step, they are just overwriting the exe and running it, so the migrations get triggered, but no extra code.
What I'm suggesting is that you add some sort of deployment or patch process where you can execute arbitrary code when the software is updated.
If you have a CD pipeline to a shared service this is easy, just add more steps there.
If its desktop software, wrap the exe in a launcher which checks for updates and downloads and installs patches.
Once you have that extra step outside of just running the app, you can do all these annoying tasks easy peasy

Your recommendation is of course true, and I support it, but it is too general to apply. I am asking how to achieve this goal if you have to support migration with actual C# code. The approach I described looks like the best for me, but maybe I am missing something (maybe someone was already in such situation, etc).

You don't go into a lot of detail on what you can't achieve with migrations specifically, so I'm answering on the basis that there is some impossible transformation and my answer is to avoid it by using versioning and updates rather than migrations. ie you have some special upgrade v4 -> v5 which you handle outside of migrations and then you make all spanning upgrades other than 4->5, ie 1-> 6 error out instead of trying to cope with the bigger transformation

I am not sure if this helps, but part of the migration is altering tables (adding new columns, etc) -- this will be covered by SQL of course. The second part is computing the values for those new fields. Writing computation on C# side is trivial, but doing so is somewhat breaking the limits of EF Core migration concepts. On the other hand writing computation on SQL side is convoluted. I am looking (outside this post) how to simplify the second approach (SQL-only), here I am looking how to minimize the impact of the first approach. Later, when I have more information I will decide what to pick.

hmm yeah that seems like it goes beyond "EF migrations", they are just supposed to be dealing with the database schema. If you have calculated fields, its unclear why you would do those on the DB, you could add them as calculated columns in the DB, or as properties on your objects?

My question is in general sense, what to do on such occasions. In this particular case (i.e. currently) I store node records, then pairs (which node is connected to which other one). And now I am changing it to have also information (per node) -- clique id. Having it to recompute each time it would be too time consuming, IMHO it is best to keep it in DB, the only problem is initial computation :-).

OK, so say you have this intensive computation, so you want to store the result, I would add this in code, so you have a "Rebuild Data" function in the code, which you run after the migration handles adding the new cols to the DB. eg. load all the nodes with a null cliqueid, computer it and save them again

Im still a bit unclear on how you got into this thing with migrations

I indeed intend to have something like "Rebuild data" and this will update affected record(s) (the one user edited or added for example). But there is one special case -- migration. Right after migration there will be no such data so I would like to call "Rebuild data" on all records.

OK, but why is that hard? surely as part of your deploy you can run whatever you like?

I think it would be a problem for any ORM. You can evolve you code however you like, but what is within the scope of migration has to be fixed/frozen. Thus on one hand my Rebuild function would use "current" models (for daily use), and "2024-08-27/frozen" models for migration use. It is not hard too achieve, but it leaves a lot of dead code behind, thus I am looking for some other approach, lighter, more fit/streamlined.

No i mean, forget about the DB, how are you upgrading/deploying this software? is it on your site, do you use a CD pipeline, or send out a patch? what?

(1) I am building binary and executing it locally (2) I am creating docker image and then executing newer image. You can say it is desktop app, no patches, only full versions, after v1, there is v2, after that v3, and so on.

OK, so that's the step you are missing. rather than just running the new exe you should have an upgrade process

Ok, thank you. It would help a bit indeed -- the amount of code would increase but the code would be separated, so I could be sure that by mistake I would not affect any migration (when changing current code).
